# Convert DateTimePicker to NTTE time format with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to change an entry inside Active Directory which is displayed in NTTE time format.
I am using a DateTimePicker and found no solution how to convert the DateTimePicker value to NTTE.

Is there a function that is able to read the value from it and convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DateTime` value from the `DateTimePicker` can be converted to NTTE with [a single method call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletime(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
$ADValue = $DateTimePicker.Value.ToFileTime()
```